# How do I plot the electric field of a ring in charge in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, plot

So I have been asked to derive the electric field of a [ring](https://i.stack.imgur.com/85mf1.png) that is continuously  charged by using the relationship between the electric field and electric potential. I have done that successfully and now I need to plot the electric field in MATLAB. I have plotted the electric field of other functions in 2D, but I am not sure how to do the electric field of a ring since I [end up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GkFBI.png) with a couple of constants and the z-component.

I thought of taking a plot from the top view and side view, but I don't know how to do that either.

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to plot: Do you want to plot a function on a torus? Or just on a circle? Can you post the example of what function you want to plot, including domain and codomain?

Comment: I am trying to plot the electric field at point P shown above

Comment: So you want to draw a point in 3d with some arrows sticking out?

Comment: Yes, to put it simply.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using [`quiver3`](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/quiver3.html). The first three arguments specify the location of the vectors that are to be plotted, the next three arguments define the vectors themselves.